# how to set a particular test file as the first when running mocha?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

Is there a way to set a particular test file as the first in mocha and then the rest of the test files can execute in any order.

Answer (score 2):

One technique that can be used is to involve number in test filename such as

```
01-first-test.js
02-second-test.js
03-third-test.js
```

So by defining this, the test will be executed from first test until third test.

Comment: Neat. Any way to prefix a file to instruct mocha not to run it?

Comment: @AskP not that I know on their official doc.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no guarantee your tests will run in any particular order. If you need to do some setup for tests inside of a given describe block, try using the [before](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) hook [like so](https://gist.github.com/samwize/8877226#file-mocha-guide-to-testing-js-L49).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way, but there is certainly a solution to this. Wrap your describe block in function and call function accordingly.

firstFile.js

```
function first(){
    describe("first test ", function () {
        it("should run first ", function () {

            //your code

       });
    });
   }

module.exports = {
     first
}
```

secondFile.js

```
 function second(){

      describe("second test ", function () {
         it("should run after first ", function () {

                    //your code

             })
          })
        }

  module.exports = {
     second
}
```

Then create one main file and import modules.
main.spec.js

```
 const firstThis = require('./first.js)
 const secondSecond = require(./second.js)

 firstThis.first();
 secondSecond.second();
```

In this way you can use core javaScript features and play around with mocha as well.
This is the solution I have been using since long. would highly appreciate if anyone would come with better approach.